# UTC time over the centuries

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, datetimeoffset

I have a question regarding the creation of a new date in js. My timezone offset is +1 so I would understand if the date created by adding it to new Date would have the same kind of querk as `.setHours()` as I asked in my last question.

```
> new Date()
2019-12-05T10:13:45.694Z
> new Date(2019, 6, 5, 12, 30, 0, 0)
2019-07-05T10:30:00.000Z
```

When calling `new Date()` my actual time was 11:13:45. That I understand. But why is when I define the hour to 12 it returns 10?

```
> new Date(2019, 6, 5, 12, 30, 0, 0)
2019-07-05T10:30:00.000Z
> new Date(1776, 6, 5, 12, 30, 0, 0)
1776-07-05T11:36:32.000Z
```

And when doing the same with a date far in the past why is there such a big change to the time today?

Comment: Daylight savings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your timezone has a UTC offset of +1. Due to [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), in June your timezone has an offset of +2. In 1776, that was likely different still.

Comment: Okay yeah makes sense to some extent. But where do the 6 minutes 32 seconds come from then? slowing down of the earth rotation?

Comment: Some combination of leap seconds/minutes/days and re-standardisation and synchronisation of time.

Answer (score 1):

Time zones were not put into use until around the 1850s. There certainly were no time zones in 1776. Also, UTC did not come to exist until about 1960. (It was a process of more and more countries "joining the club"). A generic term for [mean time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time) at the longitude of the Royal Greenwich Observatory and designating midnight as 0, is Universal Time or UT. To convert UT to local mean time at another place, if the place is east of Greenwich, add 1 hour for each 15 degrees of longitude, or if west of Greenwich, subtract 1 hour for each 15 degrees of longitude.

The databases that provide automatic time zone conversions are city-based. Evidently the database that JavaScript uses considers the time in the city which you chose as your location to be 53 minutes 28 seconds ahead of UT, or 0.883463 hours ahead of UT. 15 degrees times 0.883463 is 13.2519 degrees of longitude east of Greenwich. Check the longitude of the city you chose and see if it agrees.